# how we can use two rows in appbar flutter Like first row with title and the second with search input field

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, hybrid-mobile-app

[image]

Hi There I am working on a app where i need to use two sections in appbar one upper
1->section with logo and some Icons
2-> Search input field below the Title Section.

UI images are attached for better understanding.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you tried?

Answer (score 6):

Just simply create your `AppBar` as intended, in your screenshot, you don't actually need a second `Row`. A `TextFormField` will be enough (you will actually need to customise the `InputDecoration` as well):

```
    return AppBar(
      title: Column(children: [
        Row(children: [
          Icon(Icons.menu),
          Text('First row'),
          const Spacer(),
          Icon(Icons.person),
        ]),
        TextFormField(),
      ]),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bottom property from the AppBar widget.

```dart
AppBar(
    title: YourFirstRowWidget(),
    centerTitle: true,
    bottom: PreferredSize(
        child: YourSearchBarWidget(),
        preferredSize: null),
  )
```

But you may want to create your own AppBar widget for a perfect result.

Comment: The getter 'height' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: height

Comment: I tried it but it's raising error of null.

Comment: @FarhanAslam Remove the `null` and update it with `Size.fromHeight(50.0)`

Answer (score 1):

you can customize the size of app bar by using `toolbarHeight: 120.0 // set value`
then use **flexibleSpace** to add column or rows
it will look something like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          toolbarHeight: 120.10, //set your height
          flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue, // set your color
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [Text("Logo")],
                  ),
                  Text("data"), // set an icon or image
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      onPressed: () {}) // set your search bar setting
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but all in vain it has postioning issue more than that It overlaps with other layers and.